# Show that if A and B belong to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ then $ B \setminus A \in \mathcal{F}$

Tags: measure-theory

Q: Show that if A and B belong to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ then $ B \setminus A \in \mathcal{F}$

Attempted solution:
Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we know that

1. $\varnothing \in \mathcal{F}$.
2. If $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{F}$, then $\cup A_i \in \mathcal{F}$.
3. If $ A \in \mathcal{F} $ then $ A^c \in \mathcal{F}$.

Working with these I'll want to write $B \setminus A$ in terms of unions of $A,B,A^C,B^C$. Or perhaps, if $A \cap B = \varnothing$ then it's trivial. If $A \cap B = C$, need to see that $ C \in \mathcal{F}$. I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Hint: $B \setminus A = B \cap A^c$.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari And why does $B \cap A^c \in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: You can use the axioms $1$, $2$ and $3$ and DeMorgan's laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: $B \setminus A = B \cap A^c$.

Step 2: As $B$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ then by $(3)$ $B^c$ also is in $\mathcal{F}$. Then by $(2)$ $B^c \cup A \in \mathcal{F}$.

Step 3: As $B^c \cup A \in \mathcal{F}$ then $(B^c \cup A)^c \in \mathcal{F}$ by $(3)$.

Step 4: By DeMorgan's laws $(B^c \cup A)^c = B \cap A^c$.

Putting it all together:

$$B \setminus A = B \cap A^c = (B^c \cup A)^c \in \mathcal{F}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I guess it follows that if $A_1, A_2, \dots $ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$, then the same is true for the intersection $ \cap A_i$? By DeMorgan's laws, $A_1 \cap A_2 = (A_1 \cup A_2)^c$..

Comment: @Oskar: Yes, DeMorgan's laws works also with arbitrary unions and intersections.

Comment: So you could basically replace the second axiom with the intersection instead and get the same algebra?

Comment: @Oskar: Yes, you can define a $\sigma$-algebra using intersections instead.